# Cannot read status the monit daemon, even with allowed group

Tags: monit, system-monitoring

I cannot seem to get `monit status` or other CLI commands to work.

---

I've built `monit` v5.8 to run on a Raspberry Pi. I'm able to add services to be monitored, and the web interface can be accessed just fine, as I've set it up for public read-only access (it's a test server, not my final production setup, so not a big deal right now).

Problem is, when I run `monit status` **while logged in as `root`** I get:

```
# monit status
monit: cannot read status from the monit daemon
```

I also have `monit` started on boot via this `/etc/inittab` file entry:

```
mo:2345:respawn:/usr/local/bin/monit -Ic /etc/monitrc
```

I've verified that monit is running, and I'm getting email alerts anytime I either kill the monit process manually, or reboot my raspberry pi. So, next I check my `monitrc` file permissions to see which group is allowed access.

```
# ls -al /etc/monitrc
-rw------- 1 root root 2359 Aug 24 14:48 /etc/monitrc
```

Here's my relevant allow section of the control file.

```
set httpd port 80
    allow [omitted] readonly
    allow @root
    allow localhost
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

Also tried setting permissions on this file to `640` to allow group read permissions, but no matter what I try I either get the same error as noted above, or when the permissions are set to `640` I get:

```
# monit status
monit: The control file '/etc/monitrc' must have permissions no more than -rwx------ (0700); right now permissions are -rw-r----- (0640).
```

What am I missing here? I know that the `httpd` must be enabled, as that's the interface that the CLI uses to get information (or so I've read), so I've done that. And in terms of `monit` doing its monitoring job and sending email alerts, that's all working as well.

---

Here's my entire `monitrc` file - again, this is version v5.8, and it was build with both `PAM` and `SSL` support. The process runs under the `root` user:

```
# Global settings
set daemon 300
    with start delay 5
set logfile /var/log/monit.log
set pidfile /var/run/monit.pid
set idfile /var/run/.monit.id
set statefile /var/run/.monit.state

# Mail alerts
## Set the list of mail servers for alert delivery. Multiple servers may be
## specified using a comma separator. If the first mail server fails, Monit
# will use the second mail server in the list and so on. By default Monit uses
# port 25 - it is possible to override this with the PORT option.
#
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587
               username [omitted] password [omitted]
               using tlsv1

## Send status and events to M/Monit (for more informations about M/Monit
## see http://mmonit.com/). By default Monit registers credentials with
## M/Monit so M/Monit can smoothly communicate back to Monit and you don't
## have to register Monit credentials manually in M/Monit. It is possible to
## disable credential registration using the commented out option below.
## Though, if safety is a concern we recommend instead using https when
## communicating with M/Monit and send credentials encrypted.
#
# set mmonit http://monit:monit@192.168.1.10:8080/collector
#     # and register without credentials     # Don't register credentials
#
#
## Monit by default uses the following format for alerts if the the mail-format
## statement is missing::
set mail-format {
    from: cmn.monit@gmail.com
 subject: $SERVICE $DESCRIPTION
 message: $EVENT

Service:     $SERVICE
Date:        $DATE
Action:      $ACTION
Host:        $HOST
Description: $DESCRIPTION

          Monit instance provided by chicagomeshnet.com
}

# Web status page
set httpd port 80
    allow [omitted] readonly
    allow @root
    allow localhost
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

## You can set alert recipients whom will receive alerts if/when a
## service defined in this file has errors. Alerts may be restricted on
## events by using a filter as in the second example below.
```

Comment: hi Jeff. did you solve it ? I am stuck on the same problem.

Comment: Don't think so. Was many years ago now.

Answer (score 2):

Try `-v` and `-vv` flags to increase status command verbosity.
The next great tool to debug such problems is `strace`. Install it and run:

```
strace -efile -o trace.log monit status
```

Most likely you'll find the reason near the end of the log. If that doesn't help, run:

```
strace -f -o trace.log monit status
```

to see all the syscall-s the program and its children are making. Search for *not found*, *connection refused*, and such kind of errors.

Comment: +1 for the tip regarding `strace`, but it turned out not to lead me in a terribly useful direction in this case. Instead I copy/pasted the default http config section from the sample `monitrc` file, and just changed one thing at a time until I could get a working `monit status` to show up on the command line. I haven't yet got both a public-facing HTTP server **and** the CLI to work simultaneously, but at least I know I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

For me to get it working I had to have a `allow admin:monit` rule.

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address 0.0.0.0
    allow 0.0.0.0/0
    allow localhost
    allow admin:monit
    allow guest:guest read-only
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187786/monit-daemon-error-connecting-to-the-monit-daemon) and http://dasunhegoda.com/what-why-how-monit/756/